# Mongoose schema not working with nested object arrays (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have created a simple Mongo database on mLab, and I want to print the content on my console using Node.js and Mongoose, but I'm not able to figure out what is wrong with my schema (or something else maybe?). It is not able to print nested object data.

Here is my database structure:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5a26d0a8f36d280fefe443ed"
    },
    "housename": "my sweet home",
    "rooms": [
        {
            "roomname": "kitchen",
            "appliance": "fridge"
        },
        {
            "roomname": "bedroom",
            "appliance": "lamp"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to print this content like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var userDataSchema = new Schema({housename: String, rooms: [{roomname: String, appliance: String}] }, {collection: 'testcollection'});
var userData = mongoose.model('userData', userDataSchema); 

var mongoDB = 'mongodb://homeuser:homeuser@ds129776.mlab.com:29776/homedb';
mongoose.connect(mongoDB, {
  useMongoClient: true
});
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));

userData.find({}, function(err, data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

The problem is, the console is not printing the nested rooms objects:

```
VSHANDIL-M-60PS:mongoclient vshandil$ node mongoclient.js 
[ { _id: 5a26d0a8f36d280fefe443ed,
    housename: 'my sweet home',
    rooms: [ [Object], [Object] ] } ]
```

Can anyone please help me figure out what might be going wrong? I am trying to follow the following doc:

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is just `console.log` behavior. 
Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));` it will give you full object.